# EM field in a strong gravitational field

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, time

Imagine simple solenoid 10cm in length with given magnetic field in a gravitational field with a large gradient, for example the clock near one pole of the solenoid is running 1 second faster, meaning electrons in the wire further away from the gravitational field will feel different time dilation than electrons near the source of the gravitational field.
My question is will this differential of electron properties(slower spin, slower drift velocity) as seen from the outside observer create asymmetric magnetic field with the weaker EM field deeper in the gravitational well and the stronger EM field further away and hence create difference in field strength between the magnetic poles?